# Como centralizar uma frase com uma imagem nas listas?

Tags: css

Queria alinhar a frase "Bolos: Fubá e Maracujá" com o meio da barra rosa. Assim, a rosquinha ficaria onde está e a frase bem no meio dela.

```
Tipo assim: O ----------
E não assim: 0__________
```

Código:

```
ul {

font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12pt;
list-style-image: url(bolo.png);
list-style-position: inside;


}

< li class = " bolo " > Bolos : Fubá e Maracujá. < / li >


.bolo {

background-color: lightcoral;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Aqui `< li class = " bolo " >` e aqui `< / li >` você não pode ter esses espaços. Favor editar a pergunta e adicione um [mcve] que seria um código que possa ser replicado por qualquer um ler a sua pergunta sem ter que fazer modificações ou adaptações, apenas ver, testar e pensar numa solução. Da forma que faz chega a ser ofensivo, você mostra um código todo bagunçado que não faz nada e  uma foto e fala para nós *"e ai moleque, deixe igual o da foto"*. Corrija esse seu exemplo apresentando algo palpável, que do seu exemplo eu ensino a usar a propriedade `padding`. Faça nosso [tour] e veja [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Coloca a imagem e o texto dentro de uma `<div>` então use `diplay: flex;` com `align-items: center;` nessa div.

```
div {
  diplay: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```